# iText split tables printing multiple times

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to split a table after x rows so I do not have an orphaned signature block on a page (i.e., there is always at least one row of the table before the signature block on the page). In my test I have six rows to be printed in the table. The first set of two is being printed once the second set is printed as two identical tables with three blank rows between them the third set is printed as three identical tables with three blank rows between them.

How do I remove the duplicate tables please? The code is:

```
      Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();

      PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
      table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 3, 1});
      table.setHeaderRows(1);

      PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Section"));
      c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
      table.addCell(c1);

      c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Award"));
      c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
      table.addCell(c1);

      c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date"));
      c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
      table.addCell(c1);
      table.setHeaderRows(1);

      String storedName = null;
      int noRows = 0;
      DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

      for (final Transcript scoutNamesDescription : listymAwards) {
          if (noRows > 1){ // Change this to number of rows required
              noRows = 0;
              preface.add(table);
              document.add(preface);
              document.newPage();
              // We add three empty lines
              addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
              addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
              addEmptyLine(preface, 1);

              table.flushContent();
          }

          noRows++;

          if (scoutNamesDescription.getSection().equals(storedName)){
              table.addCell(" ");
          }else{
              storedName = scoutNamesDescription.getSection();
              table.addCell(scoutNamesDescription.getSection());
          }
          table.addCell(scoutNamesDescription.getAwardName());

          Date awardedDate = df1.parse(scoutNamesDescription.getAwardedDate());
          String awardedString = df2.format(awardedDate);
          table.addCell(awardedString);
      }
      preface.add(table);
      document.add(preface);
```

Comment: I am the original developer of iText, but I don't understand your question, nor do I understand your code. Please clarify sentences like *The first set of two is being printed once the second set is printed as two identical tables with three blank rows between them the third set is printed as three identical tables with three blank rows between them.* Also explain the rationale that made you put a `PdfPTable` inside a `Paragraph`.

Comment: Hi Bruno, What was happening was (for brevity I will only list the contents of the second column) that the first page had "Caring and Sharing Challenge" in the first row and then "Buddy Mob Challenge"  in the second row. The second page had a table with "Adventure Challenge" in the first row and then "Cub Scout Link Badge" in the second row. This table was then displayed again on the page. The third page had a table with "Art and Design - Level 1" in the first row and then "Information Technology - Level 2" in the second row. This table was then displayed two more times.

Comment: Hi Bruno, From your question I took it that the table should not, or needs not, be in a Paragraph, so I removed it from the Paragraph and the duplication is no longer happening. Thank you very much for your reply and developing iText.